# Brauer-Manin obstruction and affine curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, rational-points

I'm looking for references that can justify to what extent is the following statement true:

**Statement.** Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically integral curve over a number field $k$. Then the Brauer-Manin obstruction is the only obstruction to the Hasse principle for rational points, i.e., we have
$$X(k) = \emptyset \implies X(\mathbb{A}_k)^{\mathrm{Br}} = \emptyset.$$

Note that if $X$ is a projective curve, then the statement holds for genus 0 curves. Indeed, such curves $C_0$ satisfy the Hasse principle so if $C_0(k) = \emptyset$, then we have nothing to prove. On the other hand, if $C_0(k) \neq \emptyset$, then $C_0 \cong \mathbb{P}^1_k$ and so $C_0(k)$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb{A}_k)$.

**Question 1.** What about genus zero affine curves with no rational points? Does it immediately follow that the statement holds for them as well?

For the case of elliptic curves $E$, a necessary and sufficient condition for the statement to hold would that the divisible part of Sha is trivial. This follows from the projective limit of the usual exact sequence involving $E(k)$, the $n$-Selmer groups and the $n$-torsion of Sha. For projective genus one curves $C_1$ without a rational point, they correspond to a class of $H^1(k,J)$, where $J$ is the Jacobian of $C_1$.

**Question 2.** For such a $k$-torsor $C_1$ under $J$, is there anything known about its Brauer set? Hence or otherwise, can we deduce anything about the statement in relation to the case of the affine $C_1$?

Note that the integral analogue of the statement is not true in general for the affine part of elliptic curves with a rational point. A counterexample can be found in the paper *The Brauer-Manin obstruction for integral points on curves* by Harari and Voloch.

**Question 3.** This is vague, but if any sort of information can be provided about the statement for affine curves of genus $\geq 2$, I would be glad to check them out.

Comment: Every genus $0$ smooth projective curve over an infinite field has a Zariski dense set of rational points.  Thus, if a genus $0$ smooth affine curve has no rational points then also its projective model has no rational points.

Comment: Minor correction: "Every genus 0 smooth projective curve over an infinite field *with a rational point* has a Zariski dense...."